# Changing griffon feeding habits

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, encounters

In a 5e game I'm running, I want to have some griffons have recently started preying on the local shepherds' flocks. I'd like to give the players a way to fix the situation that doesn't involve killing all the griffons or driving them out, so what are some reasons that the griffons could have started feeding on the flocks that the players would be able to do something about? The griffons are not sapient, they are basically animals.

This seems like there's an obvious answer that I'm missing, but I am missing it, so I'm tossing the question here.

Comment: Would this question be more appropriate for worldbuilding.stackexchange.com?

Comment: If you opt to answer, please remember that we are not an idea generation website. If you've got something that can back up your answer, please provide. If you don't, please don't answer.

Answer (score 9):

### Take care of whatever depleted their original food supply.

[Griffons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/griffon) remain in an area until their food supply has been exhausted. Griffons are highly territorial, so they will not leave an area unless there are serious reason to do so. Changing the Griffons behaviour revolves around solving the issue that leads to depleting their food supply. Thus it is in the best interest of the adventurers to restore the Griffons' hunting grounds.

> ***Sky Dwellers.*** Griffons lair in high rocky clifftop aeries, building
> their nests from sticks, leaves, and the bones of their prey. Once
> griffons establish a territory, they remain in that area until the
> food supply has been exhausted.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote here. This is exactly the type of answer we're looking for that supports the method with a known fact about the griffons.

Comment: Yeah, maybe Orc raids have hunted their home area almost empty, An ancient animal-fertility spell has worn out /the artifact was stolen or damaged. Just a bad year maybe? (Remember that all food chains start at plants, so a dry spring-> less plants-> less animals-> not enough food this year)

Comment: @NautArch likewise puzzled, it uses published lore from a core book to support the answer. *scratching head*

Comment: While fixing their original food supply may be a necessary requirement, is it sufficient? Will the Griffons return to their previous food supply? As long as there are tasty sheep to eat, why go back to their previous hunting grounds? Would it be necessary to communicate to the Griffons that their original food source has been restored *and* that it may be beneficial not to piss off the local humanoid population? Is INT 2 enough to understand such concepts (compromising between deliciousness and safety)?

Comment: @RHS Griffon nests are high up on cliffs. Probably chamois and other mountain animals just taste better.

Comment: @Mołot they love horses.